# Looping through array in if statement to check if all values pass

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, checkvalidity

I have a variable 'fieldCount' that is equal to 5 (the number of fields I have).  How can I write the following out without specifically stating each index:

```
if (
   fields[0].checkValidity() && fields[1].checkValidity() && fields[2].checkValidity()
   && fields[3].checkValidity() && fields[4].checkValidity()
) {
    fieldsPass = true;
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer, which you may have missed. I believe it may be of use to you (and note that I recommend the `every` or `some` methods as they express your intent clearer to the next developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop, or some fairly standard built-in browser functions.

### Loop

Here's how to do it with a loop. This should be the fastest code, but you probably don't need the fastest code unless you are checking a huge number of fields on a huge number of items. I recommend instead the ["correct, clear, concise, fast"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3587681/57611) priorities, so think you should start with the built-in browser functions. But here it is for reference:

```
var fieldsPass = true;
var i, l = fields.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
   if (fields[i].checkValidity()) continue;
   fieldsPass = false;
   break;
}
```

Note that declaring the `i` variable outside of the loop and capturing the field length outside the loop are optional.

The first I did because many people don't know about hoisting, and the fact that `for (var i ...` does NOT create a variable only available inside the `for` loop, it is the same as having declared `var i` at the top of the function, and this behavior can lead to bugs.

The second I did out of habit, though as I said you can put it inside the loop check. [See this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974417/57611). If you do use the loop method, you're probably looking for better performance, so might want to use the captured length way for the best possible performance. (And if it really matters that much, you can do the `var i = fields.length; while (i--) { }` method.)

### Browser Function Array.Every

You can use [Array.prototype.every()](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.every) (from ECMAScript 2015 6th edition):

> *[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)*
>
> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
fieldsPass = fields.every(function(field) {
   return field.checkValidity();
});
```

It returns `true`when the passed-in function, when run on every item in the array, returns `true` for all of them. If any one returns `false`, it stops and returns `false`. In some languages, they call the same concept *all*, if you're familiar with that.

Alternately, it might be better to declare your `checkValidity` function once, instead of putting it on every field. This may not be possible, depending on how you implemented it (perhaps it has access to private variables?). Notice that the first argument of the callback function you provide (see the documentation in the links above) is the `currentValue` of the iteration, the field you want to check. If your function thus looks like this, it will work:

```
function checkValidity(field) { /* check validity */ }

fieldsPass = fields.every(checkValidity);
```

### Browser Function Array.Some

You can use also [Array.prototype.some()](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.some) (from ECMAScript 2015 6th edition):

> *[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)*
>
> The some() method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```
fieldsPass = !fields.some(function(field) {
   return !field.checkValidity();
});
```

Notice that it is basically just the inverse of `every`, as "ALL VALID" is the same as "NOT (ANY INVALID)". It just means that it checks for any one item in the array that passes the function, and if so, returns `true`. In some languages, they call the same concept *any*, if you're familiar with that.

### General Browser Compatibility Notes

Note that for these two functions, browser compatibility is pretty good. If you don't care about IE below version 9 then you're pretty much safe. If you do, then you would want to use a polyfill, which is available on the above-linked MDN pages. You would include that code in the global scope of your javascript file, and then would be able to use it as normally in IE 8 and below. (I'm talking about the code block starting like this:)

```
if (!Array.prototype.every) {
   Array.prototype.every = function(callbackfn, thisArg) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Probably one of the best explanations i've found! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of fields, and you want to iterate them, and invoke a validity check method on each of them. Only if all of them pass, the flag `fieldsPass` would be `true`.

This is exactly the behavior of [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). According to MDN:

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
>   test implemented by the provided function.

---

Use `Array.every` to invoke `checkValidity()` on each field. If all fields are valid, the result would be `true`. If one field fails `checkValidity()`, the loop would return `false` immediately, without checking the other fields.

```
var fieldPass = fields.every(function(field) {
  return field.checkValidity();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still, how about a word on which browsers/versions it's available in, and the MDN polyfill for those browsers that don't have it?

Comment: @ErikE Seems excessive, no? Almost every browser under the sun has `every` and if you find yourself needing a polyfill, it's easy to search for one or write one yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, use a [loop.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
var fieldsPass = true;
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  // Exit early if one of them fails
  if (!fields[i].checkValidity()) {
    fieldsPass = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method and reverse the logic to tell if all passed like so:

```
var allPassed = !fields.some(function (field) {
  return !field.checkValidity();
});
```

Comment: Browser compatibility table and polyfill are on the MDN link. Should I quote the ECMAScript specification as well?

Comment: @ErikE A 25k user trolling posts with < 50 views is hardly entertaining.

Comment: @ErikE Agitating and nit-picking just for the sake of agitation and nit-picking and then making fun of people because they defend themselves is basically the definition of trolling...

Comment: I wasn't agitating, nor was I nit-picking. That's the thing that's funny. I was trying to help you make a better answer.

Comment: Actually, I would love to see a quote from the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification @mhodges. I think that would definitely amplify the usefulness of this answer, depending on the pertinence of the quote of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
fieldsPass = true;
for (i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
{
     if(!fields[i].checkValidity())
     {
          fieldsPass = false;
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, a break; after fieldsPass = false; should do the job.

Comment: Well JordanBarber said he had a 'fieldCount' variable somewhere in the code(probably hard-coded) so I thought to use that instead of a length computation.

Comment: True! I missed that. Removing comment.